# How to stop VS Code to keep adding standard c++ libraries to the file.associations?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Each time I commit the changes in my VS Code project, VS Code automatically adds many standard C++ libraries to the `files.associations` list inside of `workspace.code-workspace`.

Example:

[image: example changes shown by git]

I think I can't simply add the whole file to `.gitignore`, because I want to allow anyone from the company to just clone the repository and open the workspace from this file. Is there a way to prevent the `file.associations` to change every time without losing any functionality?

Comment: @hazer_hazer I know I can ignore the whole file, but I want to allow anyone from the company to just clone the repository and open the workspace from this file. It is actually not inside the .vscode folder either.

Answer (score 10):

According to this issue:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/722 :

You can add to your `workspace.code-workspace` file the setting: `"C_Cpp.autoAddFileAssociations": false` inside `"settings"`.

You can also add this as a user setting only if you'll search for `autoAddFileAssociations` in the settings GUI.

It does mean that VSCode won't treat those files as C++ but as plain text. A proper fix still seems to be in progress in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/4077 .

Answer (score 0):

I've added something like this and it helped me:

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.h": "c",
    "*.c": "c"
}
```

Comment: Problem is that VSCode adds standard libraries and many of them don't have ```.h``` suffix